# Como NÃO deletar em cascata registros com relacionamento 1-n utilizando Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, code-first

Tenho a uma tabela `Menu` que pode ter muitas `Categories` e essas `Categories` podem ter apenas um `Menu`:

```
public class Menu
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Menu Menu { get; set; }
}
```

Quero poder deletar um `Menu` sem precisar deletar as `Categories` relacionadas. Quais opções eu tenho para resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tornando a chave estrangeira opcional.

Modifique `Category` para o seguinte:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? MenuId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Menu Menu { get; set; }
}
```

A outra coisa a se fazer é forçar o `cascadeDelete` como `false` na *Migration*:

```
    CreateTable(
            "dbo.Menu",
            c => new
                {
                    ...
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.MenuId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Categories", t => t.MenuId, cascadeDelete: false)
            .Index(t => t.MenuId);
```

Ao excluir um menu, os ítens de categoria ficarão órfãos (`MenuId` recebe `null`).